# Modifying a range reference mid-formula in Excel

Tags: excel

Say I have a sheet setup like below and would like to select the range `A1:A6`. However, instead of typing out the reference normally, I would like to begin the range with `A1` and end at the cell reference contained in cell `C3` (`A6`).

Is modifying range references mid-formula like this possible in Excel? I've tried `A1:(C3)` but that doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: Use the indirect() function to build a reference. If necessary check out excel help for indirect().